# Can anybody help with targeting css?

Tags: css

Im working on a wordpress site - bellated.us.lt which is still in progress.

Actually im kind of stuck with date positioning. It seems that the position of the .post-date depends of the lenght of the .post-author element. How to fix this? Cant make it the .post-date element position: absolute as the title is with undefined size.

Thanks!

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of how you would like to position the date span? Do you want to position left/right/center, or on a single line?

Answer (score 0):

Insert a `<br>` before each of your `post-date` spans and remove the `position:relative` attribute.